# Bounce only background image of Div not content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made this jsfiddle where you can find a slick slider with a background image. I just want to bounce only background image of that div not the content of div which is a slick slider. I have tried lots of things but ended up here for seniors help.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faisalbharde3/wfx26uzr/)

````
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Any animation applied to parent div will affect its child's.

There is many ways to perform what you want, for example try to set that background and the animation to `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements of the parent div. see the example below :

```css
.parent{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  padding:15px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
}

.parent:after{
  content:"";
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300/?blur);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
  animation: animationName ease-in-out infinite 0.5s;
}

.child{
  display:inline-block;
}

.child img{
  width:auto;
  max-width:100%
}

@keyframes animationName{
  0%{
    top:-20px;
  }
  50%{
    top:20px;
  }
  100%{
    top:-20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div class="child"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
  <div class="child"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"></div>
</div>
```